# How to set Primefaces LazyDataModel default SortField

Tags: primefaces

Is there a way to set the sortField parameter of a lazyDataModel on first load? I would like the DataTable to be sorted by the first column on render.

```
@Override
public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> loadingFilters) { }
```

On first load sortField is empty.

My solution is override sortField when it is empty:

```
if(!StringUtils.isBlank(getDefaultSort())) {
  sortField = getDefaultSort();
}
```

But is there no out of the box way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, after looking at primefaces api I think the default sort field for primefaces's DataTable component cannot be set, so I've added some code on LazyModel.load method:

```
public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {

    if(sortField == null) {
        sortField = "defaultSortField";
    }

}
```